# ngFor and trackBy with async data from API still re-rendering DOM?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngfor

I want to use `ngFor` with `async` data (loaded from API) and `trackBy` to improve performance and to update list without DOM flashing/flickering when data updates.

If data is static - everything works fine. But when i try to use data loaded from API - `trackBy` doesn't work.

#### LIVE

from API: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hx4p39
static data: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-myb6vj

#### Component

```
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

  comments$: Observable<Comment[]> = this.http.get<Comment[]>(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?_start=0&_limit=5`);

  add() {
    this.comments$ = this.http.get<Comment[]>(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?_start=0&_limit=6`);
  }

  edit() {
    this.comments$ = this.comments$.pipe(
      map(comments => {
        comments.map( comment => {
          if(comment.id === 5){ comment.name = 'edit'; }
          return comment;
        });
        return comments;
      })
    );
  }

  itemTrackBy(index: number, item: Comment) {
    return item.id;
  }
}

interface Comment {
  postId;
  id;
  email;
  name;
  body;
}
```

#### Template

```
<button (click)="add()">Make 6</button>
OR
<button (click)="edit()">edit 5-th element</button>

<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let comment of (comments$ | async); trackBy: itemTrackBy">
    {{comment.id}} - {{comment.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This happens because you are changing your observable for another observable instance. ngFor detects that an **re-render the dom when a new observable is set**. The correct way to work is to not set a new observable, is to just **push new items on the observable**.

Here is an stackblitz example that applies this approach, you will see that the dom is not re-rendered: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wslaz7

I don't know why the example with the static data doesn't re-render the dom, maybe is a side effect when the whole operation is 'sync', since if I add a delay() after the of() like:

```
this.episodes =  of([
      {id: 1, name: "name1"},
      {id: 2, name: "name2"}
    ]).pipe(delay(100));
```

you will see that it will re-render the items.

We could ask angular team why it doesn't re-render when no delay() is applied, I have no idea.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am very appreciated for your help!
I find that your code works fine without setting new changeDetection strategy. Is it necessary in this case?

Comment: I am glad it helped:). Do you mean using onPush or Default change detection strategy? In this example there are no inputs, so both strategies will give the same result. Although, is good practice to use onPush on all the components by default.